# Teradata : Do we need to lock source table while collecting stats for the same?

Tags: teradata

Procedure1 : inserting records into a table (`using lock table abc.table for access`).

procedure2 : collecting stats for  the abc.table

There can be a  chance where procedure1 and procedure2 are executed  at the same time.

1.Is there any issue by running the both procedures at the same time??

2.Do we need to specify `lock table abc.table for access` before collecting stats ??

Comment: Consider using `LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS` instead of `LOCK TABLE table FOR ACCESS`.

Answer (score 1):

The `COLLECT STATISTICS` command places an `ACCESS` lock on the table. You do not need a separate modifier on your `COLLECT STATISTICS` command. These two operations will not block each other but the accuracy of the statistics may be affected by the volume of data you are added or changing while the statistics operation is running.